# Understanding Theorem 182 in Landau's "Foundations of Analysis".

Tags: real-numbers

I do not get what Landau wants to do in the final remarks of his Theorem 182. He says something about a third case and divides the problem in subcases, but this tell me nothing. Because I can not post pictures, the statement and the proof from the book are in [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx9TP.jpg) [and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksxZm.jpg).

Here is used this [definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wuicz.jpg) of addition. Note that the case for two positives is not included because this definition is an extension for the addition of positive cuts.

Comment: Going forward, with your future queries, please insert the math directly into your query, via [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: welcome to MSE!, indeed posting pictures sometimes is not helpful this is why it is best to learn JaX